# angularJS 1.4.0 Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

```
 (function () {

    var app = angular.module("Sports", []);
    var MainController = function($scope, $http) {

        var onUser = function (response) {
            obj = JSON.parse(response);
            $scope.sport = angular.fromJson(obj);
        };


        $http.get("/api/SportApi/Get").success(function (response) {
            obj = JSON.parse(response);
            $scope.sport = angular.fromJson(obj);
        });
    };
    app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$http", MainController]);
}());
```

So yeah, this script is not working, getting the error it can not find the "main controller as function" whats the problem?

EDIT: 
the error cause is in this function:

```
 function consoleLog(type) {
  var console = $window.console || {},
      logFn = console[type] || console.log || noop,
      hasApply = false;

  // Note: reading logFn.apply throws an error in IE11 in IE8 document mode.
  // The reason behind this is that console.log has type "object" in IE8...
  try {
    hasApply = !!logFn.apply;
  } catch (e) {}

  if (hasApply) {
    return function() {
      var args = [];
      forEach(arguments, function(arg) {
        args.push(formatError(arg));
      });
      return logFn.apply(console, args); //throws exception
    };
  }
```

Comment: if you do a console.log(MainController); just before the last line, what do you get?

Comment: If you ask this kind of question - you should not use beta version of the framework. Stay with stable one.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle or something ?

Comment: @satchcoder if i do that, i get the function until the last line,

Comment: @lujcon Tried it.. doesn't work either..

Comment: @Bongo http://jsfiddle.net/bwyr1pzd/2/ Why not, just the API is my own class that returns Sports. nothing fancy

Comment: could you please provide a working jsfiddle?

Comment: @lujcon since it isn't working, i can not give you a working one, but here is something close http://jsfiddle.net/bwyr1pzd/3/ it just doesn't see mainController as a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed you [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oxfn/9nb9ar6a/1/). Possibly, problem is in immediate function. Also fixed `ng-app` and response processing

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="Sports"> 
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
            <thead>Sport</thead>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in sport">
                {{sport}}
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular
    .module("Sports", [])
    .controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0747532699")
            .success(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $scope.sport = response.items;
            });
    }]);
```

**Update**

[Plunker version for AngularJS v1.3.x](http://plnkr.co/edit/cPqbNKV64mfpDhUxdXcQ?p=preview)

Comment: This works on 1.2.x version, on 1.3 & 1.4 it doesn't

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/24qKlKNrHW5oXuIVEBGz?p=preview Can you see the code here? it isn't working..

Comment: @AlminIslamovic Your plunk does not use Angular at all. I've created other one, for 1.3.x. Seems working http://plnkr.co/edit/cPqbNKV64mfpDhUxdXcQ?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Order matters :-

```
 app.controller("MainController", MainController);
    var MainController = function($scope, $http) {

            var onUser = function (response) {
                obj = JSON.parse(response);
                $scope.sport = angular.fromJson(obj);
            };


            $http.get("/api/SportApi/Get").success(function (response) {
                obj = JSON.parse(response);
                $scope.sport = angular.fromJson(obj);
            });
        };
    MainController.$inject = ['$scope','$http'];
```

Comment: Nope, still the same Error "Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined" :(

Comment: do one thing instead of var MainController=function($scope,$http) use function MainController($scope,$http)

Comment: When I used 1.3.0 function MainController worked just fine, but now on 1.4.0 It just doesn't. It's a simple Angular Function to retrieve data from API.. Oh why did they have to ruin it :(

Comment: It may be because global controller functions are no longer supported by default in 1.3 or above dont know why it is working in 1.3 in your case.

Comment: Didn't know about the non global controller functions in 1.3+. Thanks! https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#controllers

Answer (score 0):

Here is Working Fiddle, Its just a basic because I guess you have problem with finding your controller... I hope it helps you
 [link](http://jsfiddle.net/danishn/qp2ca92v/)

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("sports",[]);

    app.controller("MainController", function($scope){

    this.msg = 'Hello World';
    });
})();
```

I guess you have have messed up with closure (Brackets defining self invoking functions in JS. ), which I have corrected.

And do follow definition structure proposed by Angular Docs.

Comment: I can not believe this.. this doesn't work either.. My God.. just what the F is happening..

Comment: What is the error in console? It still shows controller not found..?

Comment: when i use 1.2.x version it works, when i do 1.3.x it doesn't @Danish

Comment: Its working for me.. in 1.3.11 as well. I hope you have got some idea to solve your problem by now.

Comment: You can read about JS hoisting and how it works in Angular JS

Comment: Not really, http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview Not even this example works, it works on plunker but not on my project.

Comment: this example looks like basic 'Hello World' program in html. If this isn't working in your project then check your project file paths & dependencies.

Comment: It looks like you are doing some small mistake, and thats not with Angular, Its related with your files in project. Will you please post error msg you are getting in console of browser

Comment: this link you mentioned  [link](plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) , here file linking is handled by plunker itself. Its not working in your project, that means you are going wrong in path in your project. Just check them out, you will certainly find solution.

Comment: i did it like this, i got back to angular 1.2.26, and declared a global function:   getL = function (event) {
                $http.get("/api/SportApi/GetLeagues/" + event.target.id).success(function (response) {
                    obj = JSON.parse(response);
                    $scope.leagues = angular.fromJson(obj);
                });
            }

Answer (score 0):

For angularjs v1.4.x the `success` and `error` methods are now deprecated

```
 // Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/someUrl').
  then(function(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

`then()` method is the replacement for deprecated method `success()`

[Github Reference link](https://github.com/Gillespie59/eslint-plugin-angular/issues/150)

[API Reference link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)